# Change Label[,] properties at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, multidimensional-array, label

I have a method making a (new) lblArray of 35 labels, but the labels on the array need to reset at the push of a button.

So i've put the same method in the button1_onclick, but then it just makes a new array underneath the previous one..

Could you guys push me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance!
David

Some code:

```
public void CreateLableArray() {      
      LblArray = new Label[5, 7];
      int xpos = 0;
      int ypos = 0;

      for (int x= 0; x< 5; x++) {
        for (int y= 0; y< 7; y++) {
          LblArray[x, y] = new Label();
          LblArray[x, y].Left = xpos;
          LblArray[x, y].Top = ypos;
          LblArray[x, y].Width = 50;
          LblArray[x, y].Height = 50;
          LblArray[x, y].Text = String.Empty;         
          LblArray[x, y].Click += lblArray_Click;
          LblArray[x, y].BackColor = Color.Aqua;
          LblArray[x, y].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

          pnlPanel.Controls.Add(LblArray[x, y]);

          xpos += LblArray[x, y].Width;
        }
        ypos += LblArray[x, 0].Width;
        xpos = 0;
      }
    }/*CreateLableArray*/

private void EmptyLabels() {
      for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
          LblArray[x, y].BackColor = Color.Aqua;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: ok lets imagine what you have done so far...

Comment: What does resetting mean?  Must you have entirely new lables, or can you just set the text to be empty?

Comment: When you click on the label it does a series of checks and if these are true the label changes color else is stays the same.
The resetbutton is actually a "New Game" botton so the labels needs to change to their original colors
I have tried using a get set and a new method "clearingLabels" that ran all over the labels that should but the original colors back but that didn't work

Comment: provide some code to know better what are actually doing and what expect to do..

Comment: Very unclear, but start by *not* making a new array but just using it.  And make sure that the array is a field in the class, not a local variable.

Comment: @HansPassant Even if you re-use the array, you'll still need to remove all of the Labels from the form, and then re-add all of the new labels, all so that you can change the color of every Label to it's default.  Seems like more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you need to change for the labels is their color, so rather than making new labels and going through all of the work of removing the old ones and adding the new ones it will be much easier to just change the color of the existing labels.  Since you found out how to change it to another color in the first place I assume you're capable of doing this, yes?  If not, just as so and we can help you with the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Sadly I forgot the  pnlPanel.Controls.Add(LblArray[x, y]); :/
Sorry for waisting your time =(

Comment: @David Don't worry, it's always the little mistakes that get the best of us.